# replace same words in string with one of them in java

Tags: java, string

i want to replace same words with one of them

```
 "p1 p2 p2 p2 p2 p3 p3 p4 p5 p5 p5 p5 p5 p2 p2 p1 p1 p1"
```

to change this

```
 "p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p2 p1"
```

is there any method in java to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
String text = "p1 p2 p2 p2 p2 p3 p3 p4 p5 p5 p5 p5 p5 p2 p2 p1 p1 p1";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(\\w+)(\\s+\\1)+", "$1"));
```

output:

```
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p2 p1
```

- `(\\w+)` will match single word and thanks to parenthesis it will be placed in group 1
- in `(\\s+\\1)+` `\\s+` means one or more whitespace and `\\1` requires same match as from group 1. Surrounding this with `(...)+` requires this to exist one or more times
- as replacement we used `$1` which gets match stored in group 1 (so we are replacing many same words with first word).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "p1 p2 p2 p2 p2 p3 p3 p4 p5 p5 p5 p5 p5 p2 p2 p1 p1 p1";
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    arr.add(parts[0]); // Add first item

    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (!parts[i - 1].equals(parts[i])) { // Check if last item is different
            arr.add(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String str: arr) { // Creating the new String via StringBuilder
        sb.append(str);
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p2 p1
```

Comment: Small suggestion. Instead of appending `str+" "` use `append(str).append(" ")`. This way you will not have to concatenate two Strings (and use another StringBuilder).

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for pointing it out. I don't know why I always overlook that.